# Дополнение в дочернем классе метода родительского

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, delphi-xe7, rtti

Есть класс с определенным методом, дополняющим метод родителя. Структура такая:

```
TParent = class
    function func();

TChild = class(TParent)
    function func();

...

function TChild.func();
begin
    result := inherited;
end;
```

Внутри этого метода родительский класс перебирает все свойства объекта (через `RTTI`) и выполняет некоторые действия в зависимости от типа свойства. Некоторые типы там не рассмотрены, они появляются только в дочернем классе, и в каждом из дочерних могут появляться свои.

Нужно сделать так, чтобы дочерний класс обработал все свойства, пропущенные родительским классом. Как это можно реализовать?

---

Свойства перебираются методами `system.typInfo`:

```
getPropList(self, propList);

for i := 0 to getTypeData(self.classInfo)^.propCount - 1 do begin
    propName := propList[i]^.name;
    ...
    //Далее обработка
```

В дочернем классе метод родительского вызывается через `inherited`.

Comment: Покажите как вы делаете перебор свойств объекта. Также покажите как вы вызываете перебор.

Comment: @Kromster, обновил вопрос.

Comment: есть же куда более удобный интерфейс для работы с RTTI, чего вы с этим старым то возитесь. Сделайте виртуальный метод в родительском классе, куда будете передавать неопознанное свойство, и перекройте его в дочерних с нужной логикой собственных свойств

Comment: @teran, спасибо. Какой интерфейс более удобен, намекните.

Comment: то что описано в [`System.Rtti`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Working_with_RTTI), а не в `typinfo`

Comment: @teran, еще раз спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В продолжение моего комментария к вопросу, рассмотрим реализацию с использованием модуля `system.rtti` и *полей* класса (а не *свойств*, принцип один, а кода меньше).

В родительском классе определим основную процедуру `EnumFields()`, которая будет  перебирать поля текущего экземпляра. Определим также три тестовых поля разных типов: целое, строка и вещественный.

```
TParent = class
  protected
    function ProcessField(f: TRttiField):boolean; virtual;
  public
    FInteger : integer;
    FString : string;
    FFloat : real;
    procedure EnumFields();
end;
```

Метод `ProccessField`  будет отвечать за обработку типа поля в дочерних классах. В родительском классе это пустой виртуальный метод.
Теперь будем перебирать поля и обрабатывать известные типы данных (разумнее обработку вынести в отдельный метод). А вот если тип неизвестен, вызывает перекрытый `ProcessField`, передавая управление обработкой в дочерний класс:

```
procedure TParent.EnumFields();
var ctx : TRttiContext;
    t : TRttiType;
    f : TRttiField;
begin
    ctx := TRttiContext.Create();
    try
        t := ctx.GetType(self.ClassType);

        for f in t.GetFields() do begin
            case f.FieldType.TypeKind of
                tkInteger: writeln('integer field');
                tkString,tkUString : writeln('string field');
                else processField(f);
            end;
        end;
    finally
        ctx.free();
    end;
end;
```

в данной реализации родительский класс обрабатывает целочисленные и строковые поля, а вот обработку вещественного типа передает в дочерний класс, который в свою очередь выполняет ее следующим образом:

```
function TChild.ProcessField(f: TRttiField): boolean;
begin
    case f.FieldType.TypeKind of
        tkFloat: writeln('float field, value =', f.GetValue(self).AsType<real>() );
    end;
    result := true;
end;
```

вот собственно и все. Вы можете использовать результат выполнения функции `ProcessField` для определения того, было ли поле обработано, если того требует логика. Также можно реализовать логику, где очерний класс может перекрывать обработку типа поля известного родителю (то есть сначала вызывать `ProcessField` и если он не обработал и вернул `false`, тогда использовать логику в родителе).

зы: Не знаю контекст вашей задачи, но также изучите [раздел про использование атрибутов](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Attributes_(RTTI)) , возможно это пригодится. В частности, возможно будет удобным указывать метод обработчик для свойств не на основе типа, а более детально, описав соответствующий атрибут и пометив им поле. То есть даже в рамках одного типа данных, вы сможете реализовывать разную логику обработки.  А также ,  например, с помощью какого-нибудь `[Skip]` пропускать поля из обработки.

Comment: спасибо, эта реализация даже лучше той, которую я сделал по вашему совету в комментарии. Единственный вопрос: модуль `typInfo`отбирал из свойств только те, что находятся в разделе `published`, насколько я понимаю. Здесь для свойств тоже так? А если говорим о полях, то возможно исключить свойства из обработки только при помощи атрибута, нет ли возможности, например, пометить обрабатываемые поля какой-либо директивой, чтобы брались только они?

Comment: @nup перечисляются все поля и атрибуты. Видимость доступна в [`field.visibility`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.Rtti.TRttiMember.Visibility). Что касается атрибутов, то [вы сами описываете эти атрибуты](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Declaring_Custom_Attributes_(RTTI)), сами помечаете что хотите, сами обрабатываете логику. Помечать атрибутами можно тоже все что угодно. сами классы, поля, свойства, методы. Так что вы можете описать хоть атрибут для исключения, хоть для включения обработки, ибо пишите все это вы целиком сами.

Comment: при вызове `else processField(f);` выдается сообщение "Abstract error", если метод не переопределен в дочернем классе. Решил эту сиуацию через `else try processField(f);...`. Есть другие способы решения?

Comment: @nup вы небось написали `abstract` а не `virtual` методу

Comment: все, понял, в `TParent` просто создаем пустой метод и никаких `abstract`'ов.

Comment: @nup именно так и написано было: _"В родительском классе это пустой виртуальный метод"_ ©

Comment: да, невнимательно прочитал. Еще раз спасибо за такой развернутый ответ и поддержку в комментариях.